# Add links to a webgrid ASP.NET MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, webgrid

I am trying to add links to individual rows in my webgrid. Here is the code:

```
@gridModel1.GetHtml(columns: new[] {
  gridModel1.Column("id"),
  gridModel1.Column("Column2"),
  gridModel1.Column("Column3")
})
```

Table displays like:

```
    id   |  Column2  |  Column3
-------------------------------
    1    |   Stuff   |   Stuff   
-------------------------------
    2    |   Stuff   |   Stuff   
-------------------------------
    3    |   Stuff   |   Stuff
```

I also have another table that is to the right of this table. This table to the right is supposed to have information that is populated based on what the user selects in the table I have displayed above.

I would like to have a link in each row so that when it is clicked it will send the id back to my controller so that my controller can populate the other table in my view based on that id.

**---EDIT---**

I figured out how to get get the link to work, but now i am having an issue with figuring out how to manipulate it in my controller to show the information that is only related to my id.

Here is my controller:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{

    // Model1 is the model the table that will be displayed and holds the  
    // id needed to manipulate Model2 
    Model1Repository Model1 = new Model1Repository();
    var Model1RepositorySQL = repoClient.All();

    // Model2 is the table that i need to display the information only 
    // selected from the row selected in Model1 and with the code i have  
    // now it just displays all information
    Model2Repository Model2 = new Model2Repository();
    var Model2RepositorySQL = Model2Repository.All();

    return View(new ParentModelView { Model1 = Model1RepositorySQL, Model2 = 
    Model2RepositorySQL });
 }
```

Does anyone have any ideas as to how I would be able to display information that only has the same id as the first Model?

Any help would be much appreciated as i am new to using webgrid and MVC. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here's as close as I can get you on the links inside your grid without more detail about the rest of the code. I hope it helps.

```
@gridModel1.GetHtml(columns: new[] {
  gridModel1.Column("id"),
  grid.Column(header: "Column2", format: item => new HtmlString(
           Html.ActionLink((string)item.Column2.ToString(), "Column2ControllerAction", new { id = item.Id } ).ToString())),
  grid.Column(header: "Column3", format: item => new HtmlString(
           Html.ActionLink((string)item.Column3.ToString(), "Column3ControllerAction", new { id = item.Id } ).ToString()))
})
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I decided to go a different route than what you described above. I used the following method found from here: http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=655I Which i still believe returns the URL of the information in the row. I was wondering if you had any ideas to solve my issue with the above edit? Thanks again!